# OData-Version header in odata v4

Tags: odata

In odata v4, OData clients can include the OData-MaxVersion header in requests in order to specify the maximum acceptable response version.
Does it mean a odata v2 client can still talk to odata v4 server by specifying "OData-MaxVersion : 2" header?
Is it mandatory for an odata v4 provider to be able to support lower protocol version of client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a V2 client can talk to a V4 server. The client *should* identify its protocol version using the [`OData-Version`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398224) request header. If a V2 client wants a V2 response from a V4 service, then the client *must* include the [`OData-MaxVersion`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398232) header in the request. For example:

```
GET http://host/MyEntitySet

OData-Version: 2.0
OData-MaxVersion: 2.0
```

But it is **not** mandatory for an OData v4 service to support a lower protocol version client. A [conformant](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398370) V4 service may respond to V1-V3 clients with 4XX-level errors.